# Python: How do I find the list with the most elements in it

Tags: python-3.x

## Using Python I want to output the name of the list with the most elements in it.

```
List1 [1,2,4,5,7,2]
List2 [1,4,5,6]
List3 [2,5,4,6,7,8,5,3,]
```

Comment: Name of the variable? Name in the dict? Please share some more information about the desired input and output, together with what you had tried so far :)

Comment: The name of the variable can be anything for example MaxEntries. I do not know how to know to compare lists.  I was hoping their would be a way of using max and len to give me the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [1,2,4,5,7,6,5]
list2 = [1,4,5,6]
list3 = [2,5,4,6,7,8,5,3]

lists=[list1, list2, list3]
listsnames=["list1", "list2", "list3"]

most= listsnames[np.argmax([len(l) for l in lists])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBrWNbjw3RA i am glad michael jackson died. yes its good musician but now we know that our childeren can play in streets and parks safely

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than 1 list with the maximum number of items, then you can use a filter to get all the rows with the `max` and `len`:

```
list1 = [1,2,4,5,7,6,5]
list2 = [1,4,5,6]
list3 = [2,5,4,6,7,8,5,3]
list4 = [5,7,3,7,5,2,3,8]

lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

list_max = filter(lambda i: len(i) == max([len(l) for l in lists]), lists)
print(list(list_max))
[[2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3], [5, 7, 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the lists into a dictionary of lists, then as you've mentioned run the `len` function against each element inside the values of the dictionary (of lists) to check lengths and then find the largest using `max` and returning the key if the length matches the value.

It will also tell you if lists have the same length:

```
list1 = [1,2,4,5,7,6,5]
list2 = [1,4,5,6]
list3 = [2,5,4,6,7,8,5,3]

list_dict = {}
list_dict['list1'] = list1
list_dict['list2'] = list2
list_dict['list3'] = list3

lengths = {key: len(x) for key, x in list_dict.items()}
longest = max(lengths.values())

for k, v in lengths.items():
  if v == longest:
    print(f'{k} is the longest list')



>>> list3 is the longest list
```

Comment: `max(list_dict, key= lambda x: len(list_dict[x]))` (assuming a single list is longest, no ties)

Comment: However if there is more than one list with the same length.. it returns only the first occurence. But I like the approach with `lambda`!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This would work perfectly but I am studying and not able to use dictionaries.